# Написать скрипт на javascript который запросит 6 чисел и выведет все которые делятся на 10

Tags: javascript

Помогите написать скрипт на javascript который запросит 6 чисел и выведет все которые делятся на 10

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log(Array.from({length: 6}, () => +prompt('Enter a number: ')).filter(e => !(e % 10)));
```

Либо если надо читать одной строкой.

```js
console.log(prompt('Enter numbers: ').split(' ').filter(e => !(e % 10)).join(' '));
```

Либо как у @Qwertiy, но с учетем `e` и отрицательных.

```js
console.log(prompt`Enter numbers:`.match(/[-]*\d(e[-+]*\d|0)/g).join` `);
```

Comment: `1e0 1e1 10e-1 100e-1` превращается в `1e0 1e1 10 10 0e-1` - фигня какая-то ;)

Comment: Кстати, во втором варианте плюс лишний.

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert(prompt("Введите 6 чисел через пробел")?.match(/-?\d*0\b/g) ?? "")
```

Comment: Не срабатывает при вводе типа "1е1" :)

Comment: @Yaant, а экспоненциальную форму в вопросе не просили)